# Hyphen separating symbols, without intervening spaces

Tags: spacing, math-operators

What's the easiest/least ugly way to avoid the spaces around the hyphen in the following macro?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\nuSwap}{\nu-\textsf{swap}}

\begin{document}
I get $\nuSwap$, but I want $\nu$-\textsf{swap}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like a macro I can use easily when I'm already in math-mode.

Comment: convert - to text by typing the following \textsf{-}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In math mode (as in your `$\nuSwap$`) the `-` becomes a minus sign and is thus longer and has spaces around it. Simply preventing the `-` from being treated as maths as you do with the word `swap` gives what you want, e.g. by redefining:

```
\newcommand{\nuSwap}{\nu\textsf{-swap}}
```

in which case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\nuSwap}{\ensuremath{\nu\textsf{-swap}}}

\begin{document}
You want \nuSwap, here's \(\nu\)-\textsf{swap}.

And \nuSwap ping also works in maths mode:
\[\nuSwap\]
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image: output]

Comment: Ok, that's pretty painless. (Although in my code, I need to wrap the - in `\text{-}` separately, because the `swap` itself is coming from another macro.)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi good suggestion - incorporated.

Comment: a small consequence of the way you've defined `\nuSwap`, though you don't mention it, is that it won't be broken after the hyphen at the end of a line, should a line break be needed.  that's probably a good thing, in general, though it's well to be aware that it happens.

Comment: Also worth noting that the hyphen is now in the sans serif font - can this affect the rendering? Maybe `\text{-}\textsf{swap}` is better.

Comment: @Roly I guess that's a matter of taste, since the word following it is in the sf font, one might argue so should the hyphen be - especially since the character before it is a math character, to some extend falling out of the general picture anyway (if appearing within a text). of course `\text{-}\textsf{swap}` will work just fine if that's more to your liking..

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't affect the suitability of your answer. Although I'm inclining towards the `\mhyphen` answer below, having read [this](http://www.logic.at/staff/salzer/etc/mhyphen/mhyphen.pdf).

Comment: @Roly I'm not sure it makes any difference in this particular case, since your `\textsf{swap}` would ignore things like `\boldmath` anyway, which in my eyes makes a bold hyphen look strange is the `swap` is not bold.. see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GsdAO.png)

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, the hyphen is interpreted as a minus in math mode.
To correct the issue you could define a macro `\mhyphen` that stands for the hyphen in math mode:

```
\mathchardef\mhyphen="2D
\newcommand{\nuSwap}{\nu\mhyphen\textsf{swap}}
```

this can of course be combined with `\ensuremath` to get a macro that works in both modes.

I also recommend using `\texorpdfstring` (from `hyperref`) if you intend to use it in headers and produce a pdf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\mathchardef\mhyphen="2D
\newcommand{\nuSwap}{\texorpdfstring{\ensuremath{\nu\mhyphen\textsf{swap}}}{nu-swap}}

\begin{document}
\section{Definition of \nuSwap}

Here we define \nuSwap:

\[
    \nuSwap = \dots
\]
\end{document}
```

if you inspect the generated PDF you'll find "nu-swap" is used in the index.

Comment: Ah, I wondered if there would be a trick like that. I'll experiment a bit and see what qualifies as "least ugly" :)

Comment: @Roly an additional plus: `\mhyphen` obeys to the current font and size settings.

Comment: Is that not also true of escaping to text mode via `\text{-}`? (Admittedly this is not _quite_ the same as the other answer, but it's similar in spirit.) (Oh and thanks for embellishing your answer.)

Comment: To my knowledge `\mhyphen` would be a proper math-mode character, thus obeying to the current font settings in that mode (think subscripts etc...) but I have not tested `\text{-}` against this...

Comment: I do like this answer, but in the end I chose the other one for simplicity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The hyphen should be in sans serif style. However, using `\textsf{-swap}` might render it in italics, if in a context where italics is used (theorem statements, for instance).

Safe solution: use the same trick as `amsmath` for using a hyphen in the argument to `\operatorname` instead of a minus sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\nuSwap{\nu\mathsf{\newmcodes@-swap}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

I want $\nuSwap$

It also respects bold math {\boldmath$\nuSwap$}

\end{document}
```

[image]