# How might one treat hyphens as hyphens (not minus) in in-line math?

Tags: miktex, hyphenation, mathastext

How might one treat hyphens as hyphens (not minus) in in-line math?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault
\usepackage[nominus]{mathastext}
\mathchardef\hy="2D %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199504/187997
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $Hyphenated-text-string$

\item $Hyphenated\hy{}text\hy{}string$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hyphenated text string]

Item 1 treats the hyphen as a minus and replaces the hyphen by an en-dash with extra spacing.

Item 2 achieves what I need by adapting this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199504/187997).

I am using in-line math with `Bmatrix*`, `bmatrix*`, `vmatrix*` (for stacking and alignment), left and right braces and brackets, to express the syntax [metalanguage] of [COBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL#Metalanguage). If possible, I would prefer not having to change the hyphens in hundreds of places, particularly since minus is rarely used in the syntax of the full language.

I was rather hoping that `[nominus]` would do what I want, but appears to have no effect. Also, `[noendash]` leaves an unwanted gap.

The log shows:

```
Package: mathastext 2019/11/16 v1.3w Use the text font in math mode (JFB)
```

The proposed solution at [Hyphens in mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196526/187997), though close, involves wrapping hyphenated text inside a math font style, which, when using `mathastext`, I have no need to do.

If there is no way to re-configure `mathastext`, one solution, if possible, is to change the character recognized as minus to a character that, for my purposes, will not be used in math mode, such as circumflex `^` or exclamation `!`.

---

While the answer given in a comment works, it is important to note that without `[nominus]` each hyphen will be changed to an en-dash; thus, the two statements must be used together, as shown below, to prevent the hyphens from being changed.

```
\usepackage[nominus]{mathastext}
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`-}
```

Comment: ``\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`-}`` should work, but imho you are misusing math here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Works exactly as hoped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *hyphenated-text-string* to appear as italicized text, use `\mathit{hyphenated-text-string}`, or `\textnormal{\itshape hyphenated-text-string}` if you have `\mathit` set to a font other than the one you want.

If you want upright letters, instead use `\mathrm` or `\textnormal`.  You could also insert other text-mode commands, such as `\textnormal{\scshape hyphenated-text}` for small caps.

Note that `\textnormal` prevents the formatting of the surrounding text from bleeding through into math mode, but in some situations, you might want that: for example, you might want to match the formatting of the text around it if you use the expression in a heading.  If so, use `\text` from `amsmath` instead.

Comment: I don't use _italics_ or **bold** in math mode for this document, only the occasional `\underline{KEY-WORD}`, which may occur in text or math mode.

Comment: @RickSmith Edited.

Comment: I already get upright letters with `mathastext`. While `\textnormal` works, it requires that I wrap every hyphenated text string. It's a bit easier to do a Search/Replace `-` with `\hy{}` for the hyphenated text; that is, TeXstudio doesn't have a clickable font style for `\textnormal`, but does have clickable Search/Replace. That is what I have been doing.

Comment: @RickSmith I would recommend that you create a macro for hyphenated words you use repeatedly in math mode.